# How to pass a bash variable to one of the two reg expressions in awk

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I have a file where the first two fields are 'Month' and 'Year'. like as follows:

```
April 2016 100 200 300
May 2016 150 250 300
June 2016 200 250 400
```

Such data is stored for about 30 months. I need to get an output starting from April of any year to March of next year (12 months). When I use following awk code on terminal I get the correct answer.

```
awk '/March/ && /2016/ {for(i=1; i<=12; i++){getline;print}}' file
```

The first pattern will always be the same 'March', however the second pattern will depend upon user input. User may ask for 2015 or 2017 or any other.

I do not understand exactly how the above code works but more importantly I am unable to pass the user input for the year to awk and get the correct result.

I have tried the following:

```
F_year=2016
awk -v f_year="$F_year" '/March/ && /$1 ~f_year/ {
  for (i=1; i<=12; i++) {
     getline;
     print
  }
}' file.
```

I will appreciate if someone can give me the solution with some explanation.

Comment: try `/March/ && $2==f_year{code}`

Answer (score 0):

OP code:

```
$ awk -v f_year="$F_year" '
/March/ && /$1 ~f_year/ {   # removing the latter /.../ would work, but... (1)
    for(i=1; i<=12; i++) {  # (2)
        getline             # getline is a bit controversial... (3)
        print
    }
}' file
```

Modified:

```
$ awk -v f_year="$F_year" '
(/March/ && $2==f_year && c=12) ||--c > 0 { # (1) == is better
                                            # (2) awk is a big record loop, use it
    print                                   # (3) with decreasing counter var c
}' file
```

Above is somewhat untested as your data samples did not fully allow it but 2 months including April seemed to work (`'/April/ ... && c=2`). Also, you could remove the whole `{print}` block.

Comment: Thanks so much!..This code worked. I need the print block as I will be using  printf to format the output.  Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/April 2016/,+11 p' file
```

Or

```
month="April"
year="2016"
sed -n "/${month} ${year}/,+11 p" file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v year="$F_year" '$1=="April" && $2==year{f=1} f{if (++c==13) exit; print}' file
```

Untested of course since you didn't provide sample input/output we could test against. Don't use `getline` until you've read and fully understand everything discussed in http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: Thanks! But this covered months upto December only. When the year changed processing stopped. I think the part ($2!=year) has something to do with it.

Comment: Oh yeah. I tweaked it to something else that might work now. You REALLY should post some sample input and expected output so we can test potential solutions against.

Comment: Thanks. Next time I will remember about the sample input.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the hint about use of 'getline'. Read the article!